# QTimer in worker thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtimer

I have a `Worker` class which does some work in another thread, where it's placed using `moveToThread()`. Inside `Worker::doWork()` method I also create a `QTimer` which is supposed to emit progress updates, based on the estimated time the task will take.

Here's an example:

```
ThreadController::ThreadController()
{
    Worker* worker = new Worker;
    worker->moveToThread(&m_workerThread);

    // ...        

    m_workerThread.start();
    emit startWorker(params); // connected to Worker::doWork()
}


class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    Worker::doWork(const QString& params)
    {
        QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
        connect( timer, SIGNAL(timeout)), this, SLOT(updateProgress()) );
        timer->start(estimateTaskLength() / 100);

        // perform work...
    }
}
```

Now this doesn't work as intended. The `updateProgress()` slot only starts being called AFTER the work has been completed.

Comment: Is `doWork` unable to estimate the task length as part of it's execution? For example, if `doWork` is copying ten files, it can estimate the task length after each file is copied. This will eliminate the need for a timer.

Comment: @deGoot unfortunately no, there's a single call to a library function which takes most of the work time, and how much it takes can only be estimated, based on the data size passed to this function.

Comment: This kind of approach will not work. Your timer and work algorithm are in the same thread so you'll periodically need to interrupt your work algorithm to update your progress. Having a timer does not help because it will only be able to determine if it's interval has been reached if it gains processor time, something it won't get if it's in the same thread as the work algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the timer expires, the `timeout` event is queued to the event queue of your worker QThread. However, your worker QThread is busy executing `doWork()`, so the event can't be processed. Once the thread completes the `doWork`, control returns the the QThread's event loop and the `timeout` event is executed.

The simplest approach to fixing this would be to manually invoke the event loop using `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` at certain intervals throughout the execution of `doWork()`. This will allow the QThread to execute the `timeout` event earlier.

Alternative, you can use a different thread to perform these estimations. If they are not too performance-intensive, you can even use the GUI/main thread. The GUI/main thread is expected to remain "responsive" to events (otherwise the application appears to hang) so it can process the `timeout` event in a timely manner.

Comment: Unfortunately most of `doWork()`s time is spend in a single function call to an external library, and the time it takes to return is estimated on the data size being passed to it. If I could call `processEvents()` at some intervals I could as well just update the progress directly.

Comment: I assume the two options are to either create the timer in `ThreadController` which lives in the GUI thread (although I don't quite like this design as it should be `Workers` responsibility to report progress) or to create a separate `ProgressReporter` class and move it to yet another thread from the `Worker`.

Comment: the third option would be to return to the event loop (and schedule more work to be run using queued invocation) but I see that wouldn't be an option either

Comment: If most of the work is in another library, then the only option I see is to use a separate thread. You can use `QtConcurrent::run(...)` to launch a very simple thread that can update these estimates periodically.

Comment: Or, if you don't mind going outside the boundaries of Qt, you can look into OS-specific timer implementations that may offer the kind of functionality you're looking for. For example, on Windows, you can use the [CreateTimerQueueTimer function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485.aspx) or the [SetWaitableTimer function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686289.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

This probably depends on the type of connection between Qtimer::timeout and this::updateProgress.

By default, its a Qt::AutoConnection, which means that the timeout signal will be queued until the receiving object is ready to handle it. I.e. after doWork is finished.

If you connect using

```
connect( timer, SIGNAL(timeout)), this, SLOT(updateProgress()), Qt::DirectConnection );
```

the timeout signal should be treated immediately. (Make sure to include necessary mutexes and stuff though, as this is a typical case where e.g. concurrent accesses may occur..)

( http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum )

Comment: `timer` and `this` should be in the same thread, so `Qt::AutoConnection` will result in a `Qt::DirectConnection`